# How can I create polygons with user input in turtle graphics and continuously redraw them after a set time?

Tags: while-loop, polygon, turtle-graphics

Open and close turtle window with while-loop.
I am trying to make a program that draws polygons based on user input, but as soon as the turtle window has closed it will not open again.

```
#teikna villkårleg likesida polygon
```

import turtle
import time

#while True:
for i in range(3):
sider=int(input("Kor mange sider skal polygonet ha!"))
#print ("Polygonet skal ha", sider, "sider.")

```
lengde_side=float(input("Kor lange skal sidene vera i mm?"))
lengde_side=lengde_side*3.7795275591
#print("Lengden på sidene er:", lengde_side, "pixlar")

vinkelsum = (sider * 180) - 360
print("Vinkelsummen er",vinkelsum, "grader.")
vinkel = vinkelsum/sider
print ("Kvar vinkel er", vinkel, "grader.")


for i in range(sider):
    turtle .forward(lengde_side)
    turtle .left(180-vinkel)
time.sleep(4)
turtle.clearscreen()
```

I would like the program to make the drawing, wait x seconds and then erase the drawing before it started over again ... forever.
Maybe there's a better way??

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

But... it is doing exactly that?

Once you close the screen manually the program does come to end, as expected.
And if you don't, it clears the screen, waits for 4 seconds and asks again, also as expected.